# c# try and catch/ error handling

Tags: c#, error-handling

I am currently working on a program and I am finalising it by going over with error handling. I have several cases which look like:

```
int stockbankInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Here, the user must enter either 1, 2, 3. I have tried to use an if statement to catch the error if anybody inputs a blankspace/string/character or a number that is not 1,2 or 3 but it doesn't work in the same sense as a string input. Below is what I have tried:

```
if(stockbankInput == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter either 1, 2 or 3");
    stockbankInput = 0;
    goto menuRestartLine;
}
```

However, you cannot link 'null' with an integer input, only a string. Can anybody help with this please?

Comment: just out of curiosity why are you using `goto` statements..? this makes for a debugging nightmare fyi...

Comment: To avoid the goto statements (as @MethodMan) suggests, you can slightly modify my answer from below and wrap it in a while (!successful) { } block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if an int is null, which will always return false because an int cannot be null.

You can use 'int?' (Nullable int) but Convert.ToInt32 will not return null. If the value of the int cannot be resolved it will resolve to the default value of zero. You can either check if the returned int is zero or do some further checking of the returned string:

```
int input = 0;

string errorMessage = "Error: Please enter either 1, 2 or 3";

while(true)
{
    try
    {
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (input == 0 || input > 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

With this you your returned value "int input" will either be 0 or the number you entered and FormatExceptions caused by the string to convert containing symbols other than the digits 0-9 will be caught in the try/catch statement.

Comment: Thanks! This is a brilliant answer, just what I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Int32 TryParse method:

```
int input;
var successful = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
if (!successful)
    // do something else
else
    return input;
```

Comment: You can't use a nullable int in the output position. It has to be an int.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I've corrected my answer to reflect the actual type. Thanks both.

Answer (score 0):

give this sample program a try:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int stockbankInput = 0;

    bool firstTry = true;
    while(stockbankInput < 1 | stockbankInput > 3)
    {
       if(!firstTry)
           Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter either 1, 2 or 3");

       firstTry = false;
       Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out stockbankInput);                
    }
}
```

First of all, **don't use goto statements**.  They are considered bad practice, and it's like a blinding red light when reading your question - that's all I can focus on.

As per your question, an `int` or `Int32` cannot be null.  So you can't compare it to null.  Give it a default value, and then check that.

This is a scenario where you don't need to check for an *error*, but just need to validate input.  Use `TryParse`, which will set your `out` parameter if the parse is successful, or else set it to `0`.

Next, you want to loop until you are given good input.  An `if` statement is executed once, a loop will guarantee that when you leave it, your input will be valid.

Lastly, the `firstTry` is just a nice way to let the user know, after their first try, that they screwed up.